# How to display 2 types of cell in 1 TableView Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, swift4

I want to display 2 types of cell.Both types of cell is display data from 2 different API call.So the structure is basically like this:

[image]

**Type A** is only appears 1 times which is from **API method A**,which is the first cell of the `TableView`,the rest of all are **Type B** which is from **API method B**.

**In order to make this works,I done the following:**

1) In StoryBoard,I set the structure of `TableView` like so :

```
MyTableView
-Type A Cell
--My others view..
-Type B Cell
--My others view..
```

2) Both Cell have their `TableViewCell` class.

3) Both Cell have their own model class to initialize the `JSON` come from API

**And then finally in my ViewController have all this code:**

```
All the basic code here

//The NSObject class for both type of cell
var typeAArray = [TypeA]()
var typeBAarray = [TypeB]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   self.tableView.delegate = self
   self.tableView.dataSource = self

   self.getTypeAData()
   self.getTypeBData()
}

func getTypeAData(){
    //code to call API,parse JSON and also append to `typeAArray`
    //and reload TableView
}

func getTypeBData(){
    //code to call API,parse JSON and also append to `typeBArray`
    //and reload TableView
}

The code for TableView

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return typeAArray.count + typeBArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let typeACell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TypeACell", for: indexPath) as! TypeATableCell   
        typeACell.data = self.typeAArray[indexPath.row] //Here I get index or of range error
        return typeACell
    }

    let  typeBCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TypeBCell", for: indexPath) as! TypeBTableCell
    typeBCell.data = self.typeBArray[indexPath.row]
    return typeBCell
}
```

**What I get so far:**

Now with the setting and the code above,I get `index out of range` error in the part of `if indexPath == 0`,and no any data display in the `TableView`.

**So my question is:**

How to make 2 types of tableViewCell appear in 1 single TableView which the data from 2 different API method call?

Comment: Your code is fine, just reload data on both api response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay here's what's going on. Your `numberOfRowsInSection` returns total number of elements from both arrays A and B. Assuming that `typeBArray` has loaded faster than `typeAArray`, you'll get the total number of items equal to size of `typeBArray`. In `cellForRowAt` you assume that item at the row 0 belongs to the first data model, hence you're trying to access `typeAArray[0]` while it's still empty and contains no data. This leads to crash. You need to take the offset into consideration:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row < self.typeAArray.count {
        let typeACell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TypeACell", for: indexPath) as! TypeATableCell
        typeACell.data = self.typeAArray[indexPath.row]
        return typeACell
    }

    let  typeBCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TypeBCell", for: indexPath) as! TypeBTableCell
    typeBCell.data = self.typeBArray[indexPath.row - self.typeAArray.count]
    return typeBCell
}
```

But honestly, just use sections instead.

Answer (score 2):

Take numberOfSections method and do following:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        return typeAArray.count
    } else {
        return typeBArray.count
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let typeACell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TypeACell", for: indexPath) as! TypeATableCell
        typeACell.data = self.typeAArray[indexPath.row] //Here I get index or of range error
        return typeACell
    }

    let  typeBCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TypeBCell", for: indexPath) as! TypeBTableCell
    typeBCell.data = self.typeBArray[indexPath.row]
    return typeBCell
}
```

Comment: Hey sir,I tried your answer,but have a problem.Although I have 1 only typeACell,but it appear 2 times,but typeBCell also have 1 item,but it doesnt appear

Comment: Check typeAArray and typeBArray count, it will display data as per array counts.

Comment: my typeAArray is 1,typeBArray is 0,but the typeA cell appear 2 times

Comment: Can you please send array append code which is written in getTypeAData and getTypeBData?

Answer (score 0):

Obvious it should give you an error as your indexPath.row starts with 1 in your data source for `TypeBTableCell`  and your array elements index starts with 0 for `typeBArray`. So it won't match with each other.

You need to reduce value for `indexPath.row` 1 step. Also ensure both arrays have elements in it.

Try this and see:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let numberOfRows = typeAArray.count + typeBArray.count
    print("typeAArray.count = \(typeAArray.count)\n")
    print("typeBArray.count = \(typeBArray.count)\n")
    print("numberOfRows = \(numberOfRows)\n")
    return numberOfRows
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    var indexPathRowForB = max(0, indexPath.row - 1) 

    if indexPath.row == 0 && self.typeAArray.count > 0 {
        let typeACell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TypeACell", for: indexPath) as! TypeATableCell   
        typeACell.data = self.typeAArray[indexPath.row]
        return typeACell
    } else {
      print("self.typeAArray.count is zero")
      indexPathRowForB = indexPath.row
    }

    if self.typeBArray.count > 0 { 
      let  typeBCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TypeBCell", for: indexPath) as! TypeBTableCell

      typeBCell.data = self.typeBArray[indexPathRowForB]
      return typeBCell

    } else {
       print("self.typeBArray.count is zero")
       // return UITableviewCell instance from here......
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey sir,I tried your solution..Now the `index out of range` go to `typeBcell`

Comment: How many elements in both arrays? `print("typeAArray.count = \(typeAArray.count)\n")
        print("typeBArray.count = \(typeBArray.count)\n")`

Comment: A is 1,B is 1,numberOfRow is 2

Comment: Have you tried, that is exactly here, in this answer?

Comment: I tried you answer,but it seems is missing the return error in the end of the tableView

Comment: Yes, ofcouse, you are using two separate arrays to handle table. And It's wrong methodology to handle tablecell. Return default tableview cell instance at end.

Comment: Try with an answer of Girish Chovatiya

Answer (score 0):

Firstly have an **array that stores all the data returned from API method A and B**, instead of having 2 separate arrays which can make things a bit more complex but make sure your type A is the first item in in the array.

Then something like this:

```
var tableViewDataArray = [Array]()

var typeAArray = [Array]()
var typeBArray = [Array]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self

    self.getTableViewData()
}

func getTableViewData() {

    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.company.app.queue")
    let group = DispatchGroup()

    group.enter()
    queue.async(group: group) {
        getTypeAData()
        group.leave()
    }

    queue.async(group: group) {
        getTypeBData()
        group.leave()
    }

    group.notify(queue: queue) {
        group.wait()

        tableViewDataArray.append(typeAArray)
        tableViewDataArray.append(typeBArray)

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func getTypeAData() {

    let urlRequest: NSURLRequest = ...

    let task = self.session?.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest, completionHandler: { (data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?) in

        // parse your response and append to array
        self.typeAArray.append(response)
    })
}

func getTypeBData() {

    let urlRequest: NSURLRequest = ...

    let task = self.session?.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest, completionHandler: { (data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?) in

        // parse your response and append to array
        self.typeBArray.append(response)
    })
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return tableViewDataArray.count
}

public final func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let customObject = tableViewDataArray[indexPath.section]

    if indexPath.row == 0 &&
         customObject is TypeAObject {

        if let typeACell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TypeACell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? TypeACell {

            // do any databinding here
            typeACell.customObject = customObject
            return typeACell
        }

    } else if customObject is TypeBObject {

        if let typeBcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TypeBCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? TypeBCell {

            // do any databinding here
            typeBcell.customObject = customObject
            return typeBcell
        }
    }

    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Note: This was done is Playground but should hopefully give you a better idea of what to do. You should also become familiar with GCD and executing async taks sequentially or concurrently (refer to these tutorials from RayWenderlich: [part 1](https://www.raywenderlich.com/148513/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-3-part-1) and [part 2](https://www.raywenderlich.com/148515/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-3-part-2))

Comment: But how to store 2 type of Object in 1 NSObject? And how to control the 1st item in the Array is typeA? Can you show me how?

Comment: Bro,how the data model looks like?

Comment: @ken its your data model's, they are just instances of classes

Comment: What I not understand is ` customObject is TypeAObject` ,how can I know `this` object is `TypeAObject` ?

Comment: How are you parsing the API JSON responses? surely your casting them to your TypeA and TypeB objects?